# Using getline in C++

Tags: c++, getline

I'm trying this:

```
cout<<"what 2 letters would you like to enter?"
getline(cin,myString);
cout<<"sorry, try again."
```

And it prints both of my cout statements before user can input any letters? Why?

Comment: Do you know about loops and arrays?

Comment: How can I input using character array?  I've done

Comment: A while loop cin>> chararray[i]; i++; it doesn't end

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `cin.ignore()` to flush the '\n' from buffer.

```
string myString;
cin.ignore(); 
cout<<"what 2 letters would you like to enter?"
getline(cin,myString);
cout<<"sorry, try again."
```